# How to access variables in shared memory

Tags: c, memory, shared

I am trying to create a shared memory segment containing three integers and an array. The segment is created and a pointer is attached, but when I try to access the values of the variables (whether changing, printing, etc.) I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SIZE 10

    int* shm_front;
    int* shm_end;
    int* shm_count;
    int* shm_array;
    int shm_size = 3*sizeof(int) + sizeof(int[SIZE]);

int main(int argc, char* argsv[])
{
    int shmid;

    //create shared memory segment
    if((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, shm_size, 0644)) == -1)
    {
        printf("error in shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    //obtain the pointer to the segment
    if((shm_front  = (int*)shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
    {
        printf("error in shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    //move down the segment to set the other pointers
    shm_end = shm_front + 1;
    shm_count = shm_front + 2;
    shm_array = shm_front + 3;

//tests on shm
*shm_end = 10;                //gives segmentation fault
printf("\n%d", *shm_end);   //gives segmentation fault

           //clean-up
    //get rid of shared memory
    shmdt(shm_front);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried accessing the shared memory by dereferencing the pointer to the struct, but got a segmentation fault each time.

Thanks everyone, no segmentation faults now.

Comment: Tried to post suggestion here but formatting looked horrible..see possible answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you didn't include `sys/shm.h`, which should cause your compiler to spit out these:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘shmget’
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘shmat’
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘shmdt’
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘shmctl’
```

Casting the return value of `shmat` to an `int *` will also hide this warning:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

What may happen here is that since the `shmat` isn't defined, the compiler will implicitly have it return an `int` instead of a `void *`. If the address returned by it doesn't fit in a signed integer, you'll get a integer overflow which is undefined behavior, and will most likely cause a segmentation fault for accessing an unallocated memory location.

You shouldn't cast the return value of a function returning `void *` specifically to catch those errors (and always compile with warnings enabled, too).

Comment: This got rid of the segmentation fault, thank you! However, when I uncommented the print statement (from the above code) I got a "0" rather than the "10" that I tried to put in.

Comment: @user1723361: You're printing `shm_front`, not `shm_end` which is `10`.

Comment: +1.  You are correct.  And if it is a 64-bit build, then it will almost certainly crash because of the 32-bit int return that should be a 64-bit pointer.

Comment: @netcoder Ah, embarrassing. Thank you. Seems to be working now.

Comment: @MarkWilkins: Indeed. Compiling a 64-bit build will probably even yield a *"cast to pointer from integer of different size"* warning for that reason, which tells you outright it's going to break. :)

Comment: @netcoder I do get that warning when compiling. What do you mean by "breaking"?

Comment: @user1723361: I mean a segfault, most probably. You should compile with warnings (e.g.: `-Wall`) to see those.

Comment: @user1723361: Glad I could help, you should accept this answer if it fixes your issue. Be sure to read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @netcoder Right, just accepted. Is there a way to make sure the int sizes match? Maybe a different cast?

Comment: Oh, found another question on here on that topic. I'll check that out.

Comment: @user1723361: To make sure the sizes match, don't cast the return value of a function returning `void *` (like `shmat`, or `malloc`), and always make sure you include the proper header files. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your only problem but this line

```
int shm_size = 3*sizeof(int) + sizeof(shm_array[SIZE]);
```

most probably does not what you want. `sizeof(shm_array[SIZE])` is just the size of an `int` and not of an array. If you want that you should use `sizeof(int[SIZE])`.

And generally I find the modern interface for shared segments, `shm_open`, much easier to use. It works analogous to file opening and mapping and has less contraints about segment sizes.

Comment: Great catch! Blast that I didn't recognize it too :) (self-grumble)

Comment: #5 (maybe #4) on the reasons I map my shared memory using structs =P; one sizeof = less chance for error.

Comment: Right, I wanted to allocate enough space for the array. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This was really intended as a refinement question, but the formatter blew it up and made it unreadable, so I'm moving it to an answer...

Maybe I'm just looking at this askance, but wouldn't your pointers be as follows:

```
shm_end = shm_front;
shm_count=shm_front+1
shm_array=shm_front+2;
```

The first integer would be stored at the head of the block, right at shm_front, and then so on down the line...Unless the shared memory block contains some relevant info at offset 0, I don't know why you would offset these by one each...just an observation.

Comment: I meant for the "front" and "end" to refer to a queue array stored at shm_array. They would act like indexes into the array.

Comment: Front and ends of the queue? So front/end would point to the same location, initially, right?